# Debugging asserts in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

When I hit a normal assert statement while debugging with Visual Studio I get the option to break into the debugger so I can see the entire stack trace and the local variables, not just the assert message.

Is it possible to do this with Qt Creator+mingw32 and Q_ASSERT/Q_ASSERT_X?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install a handler for the messages/warnings that Qt emits, and do your own processing of them.  See the documentation for [`qInstallMsgHandler`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler) and the example they give there.  It should be easy to insert a break in a custom message handler (or indeed, just assert on your own at that point).  The one small drawback is that you'll be a bit further on down the stack than where the error actually occurred, but it is a simple matter to just step up the stack until you are at the proper frame.

Comment: I used the example with __asm("int3") before the abort() call and it works great.

Answer (score 25):

It's possible. Somehow the feature stopped working for me, but basically what you want is to stop on qFatal().
To ensure this happens, in qt Creator go to Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> GDB and select
"Stop when a qFatal is issued"

Comment: Looks like the right option (why is it not on by default?), but it doesn't seem to work for me either.

Comment: The configuration pane is called "GDB Extended" in Qt Creator 5.3 and possibly later.

Comment: Worked for me: Qt Creator 5.3 (32) + Qt Libraries 5.9 (64) + MSYS2/MinGW (64).

Comment: Works for me too, QtCreator 5.12.4 except that the checkbox has moved to the "GDB Extended" tab. This answer is MUCH better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. I have coded a BreakInDebugger function by hand and an assert macro that calls the function.

e.g: `#define MyAssert(X)  (BreakInDebugger();Q_ASSERT(X))`